# Unable to connect/initialize Lens (k8slens) - invalid apiVersion "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1"

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I'm getting the following error when trying to connect my .kube config to lens:

(This is not happening, when running kubectl commands on my terminal.  I can connect successfully on terminal)

```
F1103 10:38:50.432944 9555 main.go:82] failed to initialize proxyexec plugin: invalid apiVersion "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1"

goroutine 1 [running]:
k8s.io/klog/v2.stacks(0x1)
/Users/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/klog/v2@v2.60.1/klog.go:860 +0x8a
k8s.io/klog/v2.(*loggingT).output(0x618aec0, 0x3, 0x0, 0xc0001fc230, 0x1, {0x5885f53, 0x20}, 0xc0000a0000, 0x0)
/Users/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/klog/v2@v2.60.1/klog.go:825 +0x686
k8s.io/klog/v2.(*loggingT).printDepth(0x618aec0, 0x0, 0x0, {0x0, 0x0}, 0x0, {0xc0000e4f80, 0x2, 0x2})
/Users/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/klog/v2@v2.60.1/klog.go:608 +0x1c7
k8s.io/klog/v2.(*loggingT).print(...)
/Users/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/klog/v2@v2.60.1/klog.go:590
k8s.io/klog/v2.Fatal(...)
/Users/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/klog/v2@v2.60.1/klog.go:1490
main.main()
```

(Had tried changing the Preferences in Kubernetes section to match kubectl binary)

Answer (score 2):

As you've noted, Lens automatically uses a version of kubectl that matches the version of your cluster. So if the version lens is using is newer then your local version you will get inconsistencies.

You can update your kube config to use the correct API using:

```
aws eks update-kubeconfig --region *region-code* --name *my-cluster*
```

[AWS Reference Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/create-kubeconfig.html)

Other Notes:
Authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1 and authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1 were deprecated in 1.19.[reference](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.19.md)